# Getting Extra Rows when trying to join to of the same table when creating a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that gets data imported into it from an Excel file.

I am creating a view from that table, joining the table on itself, and adding a rownumber column. Unfortunately I get two extra rows when I run the sql statement and I can't figure out how to get rid of them or if there is a better solution for adding the rownumber/join the tables.

The original table has a row for each candidate yes and no. I tried to join them so yes and no show up in the same row for the precinct / contest.

```
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
     (SELECT 1)) AS INT) AS ID, t .*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.PRECINCT_NAME, 
        a.CONTEST_FULL_NAME, 
        CAST(a.BALLOT_CAST AS INT) AS 'BALLOT_CAST', 
        a.CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME AS 'CANDIDATE_1', 
        a.PARTY_CODE AS 'PARTY_CODE_1', 
        CAST(a.VOTE_COUNT AS INT) AS 'VOTECOUNT_1', 
        b.CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME AS 'CANDIDATE_2', 
        b.PARTY_CODE AS 'PARTY_CODE_2', 
        CAST(b.VOTE_COUNT AS INT) AS 'VOTECOUNT_2'
    FROM dbo.Election_Special a 
        JOIN dbo.Election_Special b 
            ON a.PRECINCT_NAME = b.PRECINCT_NAME
    WHERE 
        (a.CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME = 'Yes') AND (b.CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME = 'No')
   ) AS t
```

```
Actual Output:
PRECINCT NAME | CONTEST FULL NAME | CANDIDATE 1 | VOTE 1 | CANDIDATE 2 | VOTE 2
PRECINCT 1    | CONTEST 1         | YES         | 3      | NO          | 3
PRECINCT 2    | CONTEST 2         | YES         | 6      | NO          | 4
PRECINCT 3    | CONTEST 3         | YES         | 7      | NO          | 5
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 1         | YES         | 1      | NO          | 7
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 2         | YES         | 6      | NO          | 1
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 1         | YES         | 0      | NO          | 0
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 2         | YES         | 0      | NO          | 0
PRECINCT 5    | CONTEST 3         | YES         | 3      | NO          | 4


Expected OutPut
PRECINCT NAME | CONTEST FULL NAME | CANDIDATE 1 | VOTE 1 | CANDIDATE 2 | VOTE 2
PRECINCT 1    | CONTEST 1         | YES         | 3      | NO          | 3
PRECINCT 2    | CONTEST 2         | YES         | 6      | NO          | 4
PRECINCT 3    | CONTEST 3         | YES         | 7      | NO          | 5
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 1         | YES         | 1      | NO          | 7
PRECINCT 4    | CONTEST 2         | YES         | 6      | NO          | 1
PRECINCT 5    | CONTEST 3         | YES         | 3      | NO          | 4
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Judging by your sample, fastest way is to say `where CAST(a.VOTE_COUNT AS int) > 0 and CAST(b.VOTE_COUNT AS int) > 0` but im 100% sure there is a better way to accomplish what you asking for

Comment: You need to join on CONTEST_FULL_NAME as well.

Comment: ah joining on contest_full_name worked, ty. can give you a check point if you wanna anwser the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are "exploding" your data. 1 row becomes 2.

you need to figure out what the "natural key" of your table is - ie the columns that give 1 row per combination.

i think it is PRECINCT NAME & CONTEST FULL NAME 
so you can test this with a group by/having...

```
select PRECINCT NAME , CONTEST FULL NAME 
from election_special
group by
PRECINCT NAME , CONTEST FULL NAME 
having count(*) > 1
```

if this returns 0 records then you are all set and you can just add this column to your self-join

eg:

```
ON a.PRECINCT_NAME = b.PRECINCT_NAME
and a.CONTEST_FULL_NAME  = b.CONTEST_FULL_NAME
```